# daily one pager (agenda, weather, etc...)

Tags: packages, tutorials

I look for a tool to automate a daily printout with an agenda, weather forecast, stats from various web sources (e.g. analytics, adwords, etc.). Seems there is no such tool, so I started to think how to make one. My idea is to make a python script that will create a TeX file I can then export to PDF and send to my printer ... any good starting point (e.g. packages, tutorials for one pager kind of documents) you can advise? Thanks in advance!

PS. My idea is to have this automatically printed on my wireless printer every morning so I can have it ready for my breakfast :)

Comment: I look to print a page without starting my PC (I have a fanless linux server that is on all the time, and printer is on as well). Not sure how morning-coffee will help.

Comment: Sorry I've misread *wireless* as *virtual*. Time for a coffee break probably. But I still can't see the TeX question here. If it fits the page it's one page do you look for this data harvesting possibly in TeX or the typesetting? If the latter, please provide a sample file and a MWE then we can make a page layout here together.

Comment: I look for good examples of typeseting a single page document - harvesting will be via some script language (perl? python?). I have no sample file yet. Any packages / sample designs I could look at?

Comment: What you are looking for the [The `bashful` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bashful).  The documentation gives an example of producing a document with weather information.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for - I know how to generate tex file from a script and it will be easier this way than executing script from tex file - but I lack a good example / package that can be used to create one pager with different blocks (e.g. comic on top, list of tasks and weather on the bottom),  ... will check some newspaper examples maybe? thanks for help.

Comment: I think the `bashful` package is not the answer. What @Piotr seems to wants is to generate all code in Python and then run tex on this code and have some python code to send it to the printer. I think any article type class is good for that kind of one page report, there is no special class I know of. But because a specific layout is required, this might be best done in ConTeX?

Comment: [`flowfram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package might be useful here or any other package for creating posters maybe.

Comment: Do you know PythonTeX? It might be a nice starting point. I am also looking for a way to create "management reports". This is almost the same as your topic so if you like we can combine our efforts. I also just found a reference to papertex: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/papertex/